# select echo from PHP not working

Tags: php, html

I have an echo from a PHP script which is this:

```
echo "<select class='form-control' id='backgroundcolor' onchange='uploadFile()'>";
foreach($backgroundcolors as $cc => $name) {  
    echo '<option value="' . $name . '">' . $cc . '</option>';    
}
echo "</select>";
```

It returns the following:

```
<select class='form-control' id='backgroundcolor' onchange='uploadFile()'><option value="#CD5C5C">Indian Red</option><option value="#000000">Black</option></select>
```

I then use the following code to add it to a div:

```
_("backgroundcolor").innerText = event.target.responseText;
```

Where I have defined the following function _:

```
function _(el) {
            return document.getElementById(el);
        }
```

BUt instead of giving me a select option it just shows the html in plain text on the site. If I copy the code and paste it to my site manually it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `innerHTML` instead of `innerText`:

```
_("backgroundcolor").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
```

`innerText` adds the content as plain text, while `innerHTML` adds the content as it is without encoding html characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_("backgroundcolor").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;` But if you are using jquery, you can also use `$('#backgroundcolor').html(event.target.responseText);` without those function above (`function _(el)`).